# LESS CSS How to capture parent selector in variable

Tags: less

Looking to capture the value of "&" in it's state under ".media". The hope is that I can utilize a BEVM style of approach.

```
.media {

    @this: &;

    &__body {
        float: right;
    }

    &.-reverse {

        @{this}__body {
            color: blue;
        }
    }
}
```

hoping to produce

```
.media.-reverse .media__body {
    float: left;
}
```

but getting

```
.media.-reverse &__body {
    float: left;
}
```

if I rely on & alone I obviously get

```
.media.-reverse__body {
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: In short, no, Less `&` have no special meaning outside of selectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can possible solve your issue by using the parent reference `&` to (change selector order)[http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature-changing-selector-order]

```
.media {
   &__body{
     color: green;
   }
   &.-reverse & {
     &__body {
       color: red;
     }
   }
}
```

compiles into CSS code as follows:

```
.media__body {
  color: green;
}
.media.-reverse .media__body {
  color: red;
}
```